# To find the yearly growth with invoice date and sale value

Tags: oracle

I have a table with a column of invoice date from the year 2015 to 2019 and a column of sale value corresponding to each invoice date. I have to find the yearly revenue growth - I used this code -

```sql
    select s1.extract(year from dt_invoice_date) as yr, s1.rev as cy_rev, s2.rev as py_rev, ((s1.rev-s2.rev)/s2.rev) as growth 

     from

    (select extract(year from dt_invoice_date)as yr , sum(sale_value) as sales from base_sales_data_tbl  
    group by extract(year from dt_invoice_date)) S1 

     left outer join

     (select extract(year from dt_invoice_date) as yr, sum(sale_value) as rev from base_sales_data_tbl 
     group by extract(year from dt_invoice_date)) s2 
     on (s1.yr-1) = s2.yr;
```

But it is showing this error -

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 34 Column: 25

Help me to do the same in Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not

```
select s1.extract(year from dt_invoice_date) as yr,
```

but

```
select extract(year from s1.dt_invoice_date) as yr,
```

If `dt_invoice_date` doesn't belong to table whose name/alias is `s1`, then fix that. But, generally speaking, this should fix error you got.

Comment: "It didn't work" is difficult to debug. What happens? Any error? If so, which one?